# Magento Home Infinite Scroll does exist?

Tags: magento, html, infinite-scroll

I've been searching all night long a way to make my Magento HomePage loads it's list of products in infinite scroll mode, but until now I've found zero positive information about that. Is it really that impossible? Does anyone knows a solution?

Comment: The idea here is you provide code that you are having trouble with for others to help with any problems you may have.  
Please provide code/what you've tried already

Comment: Note that by default the Magento homepage does not have a list of products, so you will need to provide a good bit of detail.

Comment: go to Magento admin -> CMS. and add layout for your Home page with the infinite scroll.

Answer (score 0):

In you Magento homepage, try to get all the products you want first. May be from some category or some other criteria as you desire.

Then, implement Lazy Loading (loads images/products as you scroll down the page) to your homepage.

As an example, here is the paid extension which does this. But you could do this yourself too.

https://www.themes-mgnto.com/magento-extensions/lazy-load

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its really possible and easy. You can try out Continuous Paging Scroller magento extensions from xthemers.com.

Checkout the extension along with the demo that you are looking for.

Extension URL : http://www.xthemers.com/magento-themes-extensions/magento-extensions/continuous-paging-scroller.html

Their support is too good! they do offer you coupon code to give further 10% discount. Just initiate chat with their support and extension will go more cheaper for you.